# Javascript singleton: access outer attribute from inner function

Tags: javascript, singleton, scope, closures

```
// i = inner, o = outer, f=function, a=attribute
var singleton = function() {
 var iF = function() {
    return this.oA; // returns undefined
 }
 return {
  oF: function() {
   this.oA = true;
   return iF();
  },
  oA: false
 };
}();

singleton.oF();
```

If singleton were a `class` (as in a class-based language), shouldn't I be able to access `oA` through `this.oA`?

The only way I've found of accessing `oA` from `iF` is by doing:

```
return singleton.oA; // returns true (as it should)
```

I don't know why, but accessing `oA` through the `singleton` base object makes me feel kind of... dirty. What am I missing? What is `this.oA` actually referring to (in a scope sense of view)?

Comment: The problem you're having is that `this` refers to `window` in that context, but I'm not sure exactly what you're after here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point here is that **there are no classes in javascript**. You need to live without them. You can **only emulate** some of their **characteristics**.

The `this` keyword in javascript refers to the object which invoked the function. If it is a function in the global object `this` will refer to `window`. If it is a `constructor function` and you invoke it with the `new` keyword, `this` will refer to the current instance.

There is a simple thing you can do, if you want to keep `oA` public, and access it from a private function.

```
// i = inner, o = outer, f=function, a=attribute
var singleton = (function() {

 // public interface
 var pub = {
  oF: function() {
   this.oA = true;
   return iF();
  },
  oA: false
 };

 // private function
 var iF = function() {
    return pub.oA; // returns public oA variable
 }

 // return public interface
 return pub;
})();​
```

Notice that I **wrapped** the whole singleton **function in parens**. The reason this convention is so popular is that it **helps** you to know if a function will be executed immediately (as in this case). Imagine if your function **gets bigger**, and when you look at the code it **wouldn't be obvious** if singleton is a function or an object that a self-invoking function returns. If you've got the parens however, it is obvious that singleton will be something that the function returns immediately.

Comment: Your solution is spot on. Thanks for your note on paranthesis as well.